# Add two array of objects from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, arrays

I have a query as follows :

```
$q1 = "
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        tbl_profile
    WHERE 
        admin_selected = 'y'
";
$res1 = mysql_query($q1);
$r1 = mysql_fetch_object($res1);
//print_r($r1);

$q2 = "
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        tbl_profile
    WHERE 
        admin_selected = 'n'
";
$res2 = mysql_query($q2);
$r2 = mysql_fetch_object($res2);
//print_r($r2);
```

?>

Now I want to add the two results `$r1` and `$r2` into a single array of object say `$r`. How can I do that ?

Comment: What is the exact expected outcome? Or more importantly, what is your ultimate functional goal with the result?

Comment: i would go for BeingSimpliest answer, you can do that directly in mysql...why do it in 3 steps when you need only one?? With array_merge you would get duplicates, so would have to invoke array_unique() also (another extra step)...if you need duplicates you can do it via mysql with an union clause with both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you like to split it into 2 query statements? You can do it in just one statement.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_profile WHERE admin_selected = 'y' OR admin_selected = 'n'
```

The fetch function will produce an array that holds values of both admin_selected.

Comment: i'd rather prefer this one, fewer steps to go

Answer (score 1):

you can user following

```
array_merge($r1,$r2)
```